# Run main springboot application before integration tests

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, integration-testing

How can i run main application before integration tests by maven?
Now i have a really bad solution. Tests with commented code work properly but i need good practices way.

```
@Slf4j
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@Category(Integration.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
public class MyTestClass {

@BeforeClass
public static void setUp(){

    /*SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class).close();

    System.setProperty("spring.profiles.active", "test");
    MyApplication.main(new String[0]);*/
}
```

I want run tests by maven with arguments:

```
clean integration-test -Dgroups=xxx.annotation.type.Integration -Drun.jvmArguments=-Dspring.profiles.active=test
```

but it doesn't work. How can i correct this maven command line?

Comment: Your request to run application before running integration test is a sign of bad design. There is a coupling of some kind which shouldn't exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To run your application on a specific profile for your integration test, you need to annotate the test class with `@SpringBootTest` and `@ActiveProfiles` with parameters as below :

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = {MyApplication.class},  webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
```

The application you define in `classes = {MyApplication.class}` would be started on a random port when you provide `webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT` using the profile specified on `@ActiveProfiles`. In case you want it to be run on the defined port, then use `WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT`. In case you need to get port (random port), you can autowire its value to local field to test like this:

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
class TestClass {
    @LocalServerPort
    private int port;
    @Test public void someTest() {}
}
```

Comment: Problem fixed by your hint. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [spring-boot-maven-plugin](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin) and bind it to the pre-integration-test phase in maven like this:

```html
<project>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>pre-integration-test</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>start</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
          <execution>
            <id>post-integration-test</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>stop</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```